# Problems with endianness and bit shift

Tags: c, hex, byte, endianness

I'm doing some experiments with C on a Mac (that should be a little endian architecture), and i've noted a strange fact trying to print the lower and upper bytes of an uint16_t variable.

using the value 65534 (0xFFFE in hex, big endian), with the code below, I was expecting that the first printf would have printed 
0xFE FF, while the second 0XFF FE. 
The result is instead the opposite, why?

```
int main(){

    uint16_t x=65534;
    uint16_t y=htons(x);

    printf("%02x %02x\n",((uint8_t*)&x)[0],((uint8_t*)&x)[1]); //prints fe ff
    printf("%02x %02x\n\n",((uint8_t*)&y)[0],((uint8_t*)&y)[1]); // prints ff fe


    printf("%02x %02x\n",x>>8,(uint8_t)x);//prints ff fe
    printf("%02x %02x\n",y>>8,(uint8_t)y);//prints fe ff

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I was expecting that the first printf would have printed 0xFE FF" It does, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I will assume that:

1. The comments in your code are correct and describe what actually happens, not what you want to happen.
2. Thus your question refers to the second pair of printf's.
3. You are running on an Intel-based Mac (which is little-endian indeed).

The result of C's bit-shifting operators is independent of endianness. If `x` is an `uint16_t`, `x>>8` will always return the high byte of `x`, regardless of whether that byte is stored in the first or in the second byte of `x`'s memory representation.